# Pay with google not working in production with stripe payment gateway in android?

Tags: stripe-payments

It's working in test mode, but I have to go into live mode with stripe live key, it's not working in android.

Comment: For me in test mode pay with google using stripe is not working . It shows me transaction is declined at card number. It also shows me unrecognised app please make sure before proceeding the transaction..Please provide me a way to get successful transaction in test mode

Comment: did you solved it.?

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is 
"Request Failed", even though you could see the white window to show the cards starting to pop up, then I have the same issue.

I am in contact with Stripe support. They told me everything I have done is correct and it should be working with Stripe.

I am opening a ticket on Google Side to understand why the production isn't working. Only them can actually help now, because they will have access to the logs giving the error.

I will post here if I get any response from it

Comment: hi did you get any response on it.?

Comment: Stripe support has been amazing.

Google instructions:

Once you’re confident in your APK build and are ready for production access, please provide a test version for us to evaluate.  Be sure to include any testing instructions and/or test account credentials if necessary.

During your review, we will check for basic functionalities and branding/UI usage of the Google Pay API, and then share the results with you.  Pending the result of our review, we will inform you of next steps in gaining production access.

Comment: @KcrikK I am getting an error like unexpected developer error . can u say why this error is occurring. I have added the  permissions in manifest file

Comment: I can't help unfortunately, before this could be sorted out, the project was abandoned :/, sorry @vijju